# How to force the browser to (disregard mime types and) load the file in a tab instead of downloading?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, csv, mime-types

Say there is a text file or a .csv in some http/https url. I want, instead of downloading, to load it in a browser as plain text, possibly parsing html or show tables if it’s a csv, chose correct encoding, etc.
Is there any way to make the browser open it instead of downloading it?

Also would be interesting to know the opposite. How to force the browser to download instead of opening (without having an access to the server and changing mime types there). I usually create an html with a  tag then open it in the browser, then right-clicking the link and choose "save as" for this..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you configure this in your browser/OS. the server mime type just states what the file is, so your system can make decisions on how to load it. you need to configure how you want your system to react. also note, that when you view anything in the browser, you have already downloaded it, so the only question is what apps opens the file after download.

Comment: For Firefox, edit *handlers.json* to specify whether a file ios openend in the browser, with an external application, downloaded, or you're asked what to do. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file and http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=3034185